# Проблема быстродействия std::vector в OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

В `OpenCV` в функции 
`void findContours(InputOutputArray image, OutputArrayOfArrays contours, int mode, int method, Point offset=Point())`
 предполагается, что `contours` для `С++` имеет тип `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>`.

Проблема заключается в том, что далее мне нужно пробежать по вектору контуров и удалить какие-то из них уже из соображений алгоритма. Однако `std::vector` — контейнер, не подходящий в плане быстроты удаления.

Хороший ли вариант — не использовать удаление, а создать соответствующий вектору `contours`, например, `std::vector<bool>` для хранения свойства "хороший/плохой контур" и далее использовать его совместно с `contours`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, удаление контуров производится очень медленно в связи с тем их количеством, что обычно находит `findContours()`.

Фильтрацию можно осуществлять через создание отдельного вектора, который будет содержать индексы интересующих контуров. Новый вектор получится меньшего размера, чем исходный, что положительно скажется на скорости последующих итераций.

Заполнять же `std::vector<bool>` значениями "хороший" / "плохой" не имеет смысла, если Вам "плохие" вовсе не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Самый правильный вариант - не гадать (и не заставлять гадать сообщество), а сделать таки бенчмарк.

У вас четыре(три моих, один предложили в комментариях) варианта

- оставить как есть, и удалять из вектора
- скопировать в `list` и удалять из него
- ваш вариант с дополнительным массивом
- скопировать нужное в новый вектор, а старый удалить (кандидат на рекорд по скорости)

У всех вариантов есть как плюсы, так и минусы. Бенчмарк рассудит.

Comment: Вариантов, я думаю, куда больше. Например, создать новый вектор и просто скопировать в него всё, что надо, а старый удалить.

Comment: Не знала про бенчмарки, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Проведите [профилирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%28%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29) кода для выявления узких мест. И выбирайте контейнер согласно предъявляемым к нему требованиям. [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/194726/) можно посмотреть любопытную блок-схему.